# HTML Service Slow

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create an add-on for Google Docs using a modal dialog with the HTML Service but the time between running my script and something happening in the dialog window is pretty slow.

Here's a really simple  example. (It's a little hack-y because calling foo from Example.html overwrites the first log)

```
// Code.gs
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Example')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

  Logger.log("hi");
  var temp = Logger.getLog();

  DocumentApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, temp);
}

function foo() {
  Logger.log("bye");
}
```

and

```
// Example.html
<script>google.script.run.foo();</script>
```

If I run this there's a ~4 second difference between the first log and the second log. Is this just the way it is?

Comment: The situation hasn't changed 3 years later :(

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes. Your approach is among the best ways to call a server-side function.

Long answer: Per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices), try [loading data asynchronously](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates). It says -

> [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) can be used to quickly build simple interfaces, but its use should be limited to ensure your UI is responsive. The code in templates is executed once when the page is loaded, and no content is sent to the client until the processing is complete. Having long-running tasks in your scriptlet code can cause your UI to appear slow.

You could also try providing spinners / pre-loaders in the UI too and that should help with improving UX.

It also recommends us to [Use the HTML5 document type declaration](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#use_the_html5_document_type_declaration) i.e.

> If your page is served using the newer `IFRAME` [sandbox mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#sandbox_mode), make sure to include the following snippet of code at the top of you HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Hope this helps.